# How to change the joget base url

Tags: config, base-url, joget

I want to change the joget base url. For example, the default url is http://domian/jw. I want to all my joget url having a prefix with `/url1/url2` like `http://domian/url1/url2/jw/...`

Any one can help me to solve the problem? Very thanks

I have tried to build a folders in webapp with `url1/url2`. Then I copy the jw folder under the `url1/url2`. This way is not work. The `index.jsp` in `jw`  folder will redirect the page to the wrong `url`.

Another way I tried is that I add a nginx server, and I proxy the request with `/url1/url2` to the joget server. Again, some codes in web pages will redirect to the wrong url.